# Markov Model diagram directly from data (makovchain or deemod package?)

Tags: r, graph, markov-models

I want to read a bunch of factor data and create a transition matrix from it that I can visualise nicely. I found a very sweet package, called 'heemod' which, together with 'diagram' does a decent job.

For my first quick-and-dirty approach, a ran a piece of Python code to get to the matrix, then used this R sniplet to draw the graph. Note that the transition probabilities come from that undisclosed and less important Python code, but you can also just assume that I calculated it on paper.

```
library('heemod')
library('diagram')
mat_dim <- define_transition(
  state_names = c('State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C'),
  .18, .73, .09, 
  .22, .0, .78,
  .58, .08, .33);
plot(mat_dim)
```

However, I would like to integrate all in R and generate the transition matrix and the graph within R and from the sequence data directly.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(markovchain)
library('heemod')
library('diagram')

# the data --- this is normally read from a file
data = c(1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,1)
fdata = factor(data)
rdata = factor(data,labels=c("State_A","State_B","State_C"))

# create transition matrix
dimMatrix = createSequenceMatrix(rdata, toRowProbs = TRUE)
dimMatrix
```

QUESTION: how can I transfer dimMatrix so that define_transition can process it?

```
mat_dim <- define_transition( ??? );
plot(mat_dim)
```

Any ideas? Are there better/easier solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to `define_transition` seems to be quite awkward. Perhaps this is due to my inexperience with the `heemod` package but it seems the only way to input transitions is element by element.

Here is a workaround

```
library(heemod)
library(diagram)
```

first convert the transition matrix to a list. I used rounding on the digits which is optional. This corresponds to the `...` variables in `define_transition`

```
lis <- as.list(round(dimMatrix, 3))
```

now add to the list all other named arguments you wish:

```
lis$state_names = colnames(dimMatrix)
```

and now pass these arguments to `define_transition` using `do.call`:

```
plot(do.call(define_transition, lis))
```

[image]

Update: to the question in the comments:

```
lis <- as.list(t(round(dimMatrix, 3)))
lis$state_names = colnames(dimMatrix)
plot(do.call(define_transition, lis))
```

[image]

The reasoning behind `do.call`

The most obvious way (which does not work here) is to do:

```
define_transition(dimMatrix, state_names = colnames(dimMatrix))
```

however this throws an error since the `define_transition` expects each transition to be supplied as an argument and not as a matrix or a list. In order to avoid typing:

```
define_transition(0.182, 0.222,..., state_names = colnames(dimMatrix))
```

one can put all the arguments in a list and then call `do.call` on that list as I have done.

Comment: This works. However, I am just wondering why the following code does not do the same here? mat_dim <- define_transition(lis);
plot(mat_dim) Is do.call do anything more than calling define_transition with that list?

Comment: Also, the probabilities seem reverted (e.g. the original probability of State_A to State_B seem to be the probability of State_B transitioning  to State_A). Did I do something wrong here or did the list perhaps mix something up?

Comment: `do.call` calls a function, in this case `define_transition` on a list of arguments in this case all arguments are in `lis`, I have performed this in such a way since I see no other way to pass a transition matrix in an R object. If the probabilities are reversed then a `transpose` prior to `unlist` can be performed. Check edit please.